# openssl is not recognized in command prompt - Android?

Tags: android, facebook

I want to generate application signature for my application for facebook integration in android.

In facebook integration tutorial(androidhive) i found this command line

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "&lt;path-to-users-directory&gt;\.android\debug.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

when I run the command prompt its showing error-

> openssl is not recognized as internal or external command

This is the path of my openssl-

> D:\openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32\bin

and this is the path for .android keystore-

> D:.android/debug.keystore

guide me how to get the key.

Comment: you need to install openssl

Comment: find here http://pubs.vmware.com/vfabric53/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vfabric.gemfire.7.0/gemfire_nativeclient/security/1downloadinstallopenssl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code in your command prompt

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "d:\.android\.keystore" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

give this before your path

```
c:\Program files\GnuWin32>
```

Answer (score 9):

Steps to create Hash Key.

1. Download openssl from Openssl for Windows . I downloaded the Win32 version
2. Unzip and copy all the files in the bin folder including openssl.exe
3. Goto to the folder where you installed JDK for me it’s C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin
4. Paste all the files you copied from Openssl’s bin folder to the Jdk folder.

Then run `keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "your path" | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Answer (score 0):

1. Download openssl from Openssl for Windows . for your PC.
2. Unzip and copy Somewhere in C:/
3. Open command prompt (cmd)  and navigate to the folder of the where you extracted the zip
   move to the bin directory and type

keytool -exportcert -alias  -keystore  | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64

is to be change to your app name.